# Is there a html tag filter for the excerpt?

Tags: excerpt

Maybe now, with the wordpress 3.6, there is a filter on allowing html tags on the_excerpt()

I am trying to get the_excerpt() to allow certain html tags and I searched and searched and all I find is outdated info.

What is a valid method to do it?

Comment: maybe you can do somthing with the `esc_html` filter

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in HTML formatting within [custom excerpts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt#How_to_add_excerpts_to_posts) and output it via `the_excerpt()` or `get_the_excerpt()` in your template files.

Check your template files for additional custom filters added to `the_excerpt()` or `get_the_excerpt()` if the HTML formatting is removed anyway.